# Install old OpenSSL 0.9.8 on MacOS 13.2, make error

Tags: mac-osx, openssl, make

for compatibility purpose of some functionalities and old softwares I need to install OpenSSL0.9.8 on a modern MacOS machine.
I downloaded the source archive from: https://www.openssl.org/source/old/0.9.x/openssl-0.9.8i.tar.gz
I unpacked the tar, launched the Configure, fixed some lines in the Makefile, but when I launch the `make all` I get this error:

```
[...]
      "_sk_zero", referenced from:
          _ssl_bytes_to_cipher_list in libssl.a(ssl_lib.o)
      "_uni2asc", referenced from:
          _print_attribs in pkcs12.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[2]: *** [link_app.] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [openssl] Error 2
    make: *** [build_apps] Error 1
```

I tried to understand how to fix or bypass this, but to no avail.
Does anyone have any suggestion on how to adress this?
Thank you in advance.